# What is the right way to present data from Realm in SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swiftui, swiftui-list

I’m trying to fetch all of the items from `Realm` and display them in a `SwiftUI List` but I keep getting an error.

In a `UIKit/Realm` application, I would just create a `Results` variable to store all of the items from `Realm` then, I would fetch items in the `viewDidLoad` method and assign them to the variable. I'm trying to do the same thing in `SwiftUI` but I'm not sure how to structure my code, I keep getting an error saying that my `Realm` model should conform to the `StringProtocol`, I'm pretty sure this has to do with my lack of understanding `Binding` in `SwiftUI`.

Again, all I’m trying to do is fetch all of the items from `Realm` and display them in a `SwiftUI List`.

Here is what I have.

### Realm Object:

```
class User:Object{
    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var age:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    @objc dynamic var userID = UUID().uuidString
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userID"
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var allUsers : Results<User>!
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(allUsers, id:\.self) { user in
                    Text(user) // the error points here
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(){
            self.updateUserResults()
        }
    }
    func updateUserResults(){
        allUsers = realm.objects(User.self)
    }
}
```

### Error:

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'User' conform to 'StringProtocol'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you meant this

```
ForEach(allUsers, id:\.self) { user in
    Text(user.name)
}
```

Comment: That definitely got rid of the error now I get error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` in line `ForEach(allUsers, id:\.self) { user in`. Does the call to `self.updateUserResults()`  in `.onAppear()` looks fine? I maybe the `List` is loading before fetching the users. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre, it really does. You have to give some default empty value for `allUsers`.

Comment: Hmm, I honestly don't know how to add default values. I tried making `allUsers` an optional but no luck. FYI - I'm sure I have records in the `Realm` database. Thanks

Comment: I changed `allUsers` to fetch all of the users at the variable declaration `@State private var allUsers: Results<User> = realm.objects(User.self)`and now it works. I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one since it led me to a solution.