# Updating @Published variables in SwiftUI/Realm from different threads

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have an @Published variable in my datamodel class that is populated in the init(){} function to contain the Realm objects.

```
class DataModel : ObservableObject {
@Published objectArray: [RealmObject] = []

   init() {
     let realm = try! Realm()
     objectArray = Array(realm.objects(RealmObject.self))
   }

   bigCompute() {
      DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
            let realm = try! Realm()

             **** code that generates new RealmObject *****
            realm.write {
                realm.add(RealmObject)
            }
      }
   }
}
```

This works just fine, but obviously doesn't update the objectArray.  I have a bigcomputation() that needs to happen on a background thread, and the results will store a new RealmObject.  Which I will then want to display on a different view that subscribes to the DataModel.objectArray

Other view:

```
struct PersonView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var datamodel: dataModel

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        
            List {
                ForEach(datamodel.objectArray, id: \.self) { obj in
                        VStack {
                            Text(obj.name)
                                .font(.title)
                            Text("\(obj.chr)")
                                .font(.title2)
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to update objectArray from a background thread so that my other view that subscribes to it updates automatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160102/what-is-the-right-way-to-present-data-from-realm-in-swiftui-list?

Comment: Mostly!   Though I have no idea how they declared their @state variable and immediately populated it from realm.   I simply can't get that to work...

Comment: Another one with view model and handling while loading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65442296/swiftui-with-mvvm-realm-database-how-to-create-a-list-with-elements.

Comment: More generally, is it possible to update a @published object or state object of type Realm Object from a background thread?

Comment: It should be done from `DispatchQueue.main.async { /* here */ }` because those dynamic properties refresh UI, so should not be updated from other threads.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.    My problem was I created a Realm Object from a background thread that I was using 'main.async' to add onto the @Published variable